# Control stepper motor with low current and high current

Tags: current, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I am learning about stepper motors and i have the following question. Let's say i have a bipolar, 2 phases, NEMA34 with a 5A rated current. I am using a driver capable of delivering 5Amps or 2Amps at a voltage between 24-80V. How will affect these different current values the behaviour of my stepper motor?
First i set the current limit to 5A and then to 2A. In conclusion, how does adjusting the current limit of my driver affect the stepper motor?

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the current of a stepper motor will not reduce its precision but it will reduce its "holding torque" feature. The holding torque is the ability of the stepper motor to keep its position when a torque is applied on its axis of rotation. If we take [this one](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/nema-34-stepper-motor/economic-nema-34-stepper-motor-bipolar-1-8deg-4-8-nm-679-87oz-in-6-0a-86x86x80mm-4-wires.html) for example, it is not explicit but the max holding torque (4.8 Nm) is directly linked to the rated current per phase (6.0 A). I don't remember the exact equation linking the holding torque to the amperage but if you reduce the current, the holding torque will also decrease. If you intend to use a stepper motor not only to precisely move but also to stay in place when an external torque is applied (like holding a weight), you should take care of the current you are providing to the stepper motor.